# Why can't I boot into Ubuntu?

Tags: boot

Today, I have an unusual case with this laptop lenovo v310-14-ISK. The problem is whenever I install through "*Something else*" path, I can't get the system boot into Ubuntu (which I'd been doing successfully several times in other PC/laptop), instead when I choose "*Erase disk and install Xubuntu*" path it work like charm. Still I have to go for "Something else" path because I need partition out my /home.

Here's how I do the partition:

[image]

[image]

Then when it finish and reboot, I got this view instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only advantage of a separate home partition is in the event of reinstalls. I understand there are no speed increases. So for normal use, Xubuntu's default scheme would suit most use cases. However, should you require a separate home partition:

Try starting fresh with only these partitions in order:

/

home

swap

Not sure why you'd need efi boot partition. If this disk has had an operating system previously, format the disk and start fresh.

Comment: I have tried such partition but it didn't work. It kept showing boot menu. Yes I did using gparted to format the disk.